# SQL Connection timeout using entity framework

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework

I am running a entity framework on the distributed database server. I am facing the connection timeout exception occasionally and it occurs only two to three times in a day. The actual .Net exception is:

```
System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner
exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.The timeout
period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior
runBehavior,String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior
runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior
runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String
 methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator,
EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager,
IEntityAdapter adapter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager,
IEntityAdapter adapter)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
at INW.BusinessLogicLayer.DataAccessLayer.FinishOrder(OrderHandlerRequest req, Guid userId)
at INW.BusinessLogicLayer.Objects.Order.OrderHandler.FinishOrder(OrderHandlerRequest req,
MembershipUser loggedinUser)
at INW.BusinessLogicLayer.Objects.PaymentGateway.PGHelper.ProcessRequest(String requestStr,
UserControl control, MembershipUser loggedInUser)
at INW.WebService.Insolvency.UpdatePaymentAuthorisationResultRequest(String
PaymentAuthorisationResult)
```

My connection string is:

```
<add name="InsolvencyEntities"
connectionString="metadata=res://*/InsolvencyDB.csdl|res://*/InsolvencyDB.ssdl|res://*/
InsolvencyDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data
Source=*.net.au;Failover Partner=*.net.au;Initial
Catalog=INWDAP;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

There are some of the error that I have noticed occurring in the SQL Logs

Date        20/10/2014 4:51:55 PM
Log     SQL Server (Current - 21/10/2014 4:15:00 PM)

Source      Logon

Message
Login failed for user 'abc\xyz$'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: 113.192.23.72]

I don't know why the timeout occurs but it occurs occasionally. can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Can we start with that it is not a connection timeout, dude? COnnection timeout is when you CONNECT. Command timeout is for commands. And this obviously is a command timeout. And it happens occasionally because the database overloads. Why do traffic jams happen? Start debugging - if the db is done as this query you likely miss relevant indices and are dead slow because of this. Nothing EF specific here.

Comment: Thanks Tom, Yeah I know but this is not a complex query and it is just doing a simple update to the database. I will run a debug to see why the database is unable to process this query.

Comment: Well, an update needs a lock on the row or table. If a query blockjs it long enough - timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you think if I set a command timeout to lets say 2 min when executing that particular query might help me resolving this problem? I don't think the website has got that much traffic. Do you think it might be an issue as the website has got distributed database and it is unable to lock the particular table at the execution of the query ?

Comment: You can extend the timeout and it might work but you should fix the underlying problem. `Failed to open the explicitly specified database` means that a user tried to connect to a specific database (INWDAP?) but did not have correct access. You should check user `abc\xyz$` and ensure they have correct access. This probably doesn't have anything to do with your timeout issue, but if you clean up those spurious messages it will make it easier to solve